# Adding keys and value pair to a dictionary within a dictionary with duplicate keys

Tags: python-3.x

results is a list within a list with the data as shown in the results section. I am hoping to achieve a dictionary within a dictionary as shown in the results portion.

input:

```
results = [['abc','12'3,'1123','qwe', 'asd'],['abc','123,'1123','qwe', '123'],['abc','123','1123','ewq','zxc'], ['bcd','123','1123','ewq','zxc'], ['bcd','123','1123','ewq','zxc]]
```

Code:

```
report_dict = dict()
axis_list = []
results = self.report_data(conn)
for row in results:
  try:
    report_dict[row[0]] = {}
    report_dict[row[0]][row[3]] = row[1]
  except IndexError:
    None 
  print(report_dict)
```

Result:

```
report_dict = { 'abc': {'qwe':['asd','123'], 'ewq':['zxc']}, 'bcd' : {'qwe':['asd'], 'ewq':['zxc']} …..}
```

Please note there are duplicate keys in the dataset.

Comment: Dictionaries *can't* have duplicate keys.  What is in `results`?

Comment: @ScottHunter Results is a list within a list with data in it like shown in result section.

Comment: Are you asking about how to combine your `abc`'s? Try using `import collections; report_dict = collections.defaultdict(dict)`

Comment: @EdWard I don't want to combine them. I want to essentially have multiple abc's with different qwe:asd as shown. is this not possible?

Comment: It would be possible, if you used list with `(key, value)` pairs, but not with dictionaries. Why do you **need** to have multiple ones?

Comment: @EdWard How would you combine them? I can work with combining them. I guess what I don't understand is how would match each row to the correct key using collections

Comment: Would something like `{ abc: {qwe:asd, ewq:zxc}, ...}` work?

Comment: @fabianegli yes, please see the updated result

Comment: please prepare a [mcve]

Comment: Do you expect duplicate the same key in multiple dictionaries within the lists? If so, you may use tuples inside the lists if not, you can remove the lists entirely.

Comment: @fabianegli no I am not going to duplicate any keys. the list is a collection of dictionaries. I have updated the result. The lists weren't needed youre correct.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh I have provided the input parameters as well

Comment: Will you have another `abc:{...}` in your dictionary?

Comment: @Onyambu I will not. The duplicate keys data is in the input dataset

Comment: Why are there lots of variable names in your list of lists? your `results` will lead to NameError - please prepare a [mre] of your problem - your result also contains plenty of variables hich will never print like this

Comment: @PatrickArtner What do you mean? Its just dummy data I have put in if youre referring to 'qwe' etc.

Comment: @qwerty good attempt at an example. what Patrick is referring to is the fact that your example isn't yet valid code, since you forgot to use quotes around strings. (so it's not strings, it's variables.) edit: to be technical, it *is* valid code, but would result in nameerrors, but that's beside the fact that you intended those to be strings, not variable names. referring to `qwe`, `asd`

Comment: @ParitoshSingh Thanks... made the edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do:

```
d = {}
for i in results:
   if not d.get(i[0],0):
      d[i[0]] = {}
   if not d[i[0]].get(i[3],0):
      d[i[0]][i[3]] = []
   d[i[0]][i[3]].append(i[4])
d
{'abc': {'qwe': ['asd', '123'], 'ewq': ['zxc']}, 'bcd': {'ewq': ['zxc', 'zxc']}}
```

Comment: One question, what if the input has multiple "qwe" ? so like the final result would be `{abc:{qwe:[123,321]},....}` I can edit the question to provide more details if you'd like

Comment: @qwerty you will have to ask a different question./ edit your question

Comment: is d a defaultdict?

Comment: @qwerty. No I did not import any modules. d is an empty dictionary. Defined as shown in the code

Comment: Wont this give a keyerror as the second key wont be in there?

Comment: @qwerty try running it first. The if statements takes that into consideration hence no errors

Answer (score 1):

The following is a solution to your immediate question with tuples in the list:

```
from collections import defaultdict
report_dict = defaultdict(list)
# results = self.report_data(conn)
results = [["abc",123,1123,"qwe", "asd"],["abc",123,1123,"ewq","zxc"], ["bcd",123,1123,"ewq","zxc"], ["bcd",123,1123,"ewq","zxc"]]
for row in results:
    try:
        report_dict[row[0]].append((row[3], row[1]))
    except IndexError:
        None 
print(report_dict)
```

Result: `defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'abc': [('qwe', 123), ('ewq', 123)], 'bcd': [('ewq', 123), ('ewq', 123)]})`

you can also change it to a dictionaries in the list with the following line

```
        report_dict[row[0]].append({row[3]: row[1]})
```

Result: `defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'abc': [{'qwe': 123}, {'ewq': 123}], 'bcd': [{'ewq': 123}, {'ewq': 123}]})`

Comment: One question, what if the input has multiple "qwe" ? so like the final result would be `{abc:{qwe:[123,321]},....}` I can edit the question to provide more details if you'd like